# Qual a diferença de Gíria ou calão?

Tags: linguística

Qual a diferença de Gíria e calão no Português?

What is the difference between Gíria and calão in Portuguese?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Gíria** e **calão** são **sinónimos** tanto em Portugal como no Brasil. É muito comum haver confusão de **calão** com **baixo calão<sup>1</sup>** porque na realidade **baixo calão<sup>1</sup>** é um sub conjunto de **calão**. Além disso, é comum no dia-a-dia usar-mos o termo **calão** para nos referirmos ao **baixo calão<sup>1</sup>**.

*The words are **synonymous** in both Portugal and Brazil.*

[Definição de Calão [pt_BR]](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=cal%E3o)

> 1. Linguagem especial, peculiar a ciganos, fadistas, larápios, vadios  etc.
> 2. **Gíria**, geringonça.

[Definição de Calão [pt_PT]](http://www.lexico.pt/calao/)

> 1. linguagem específica de um grupo: o calão médico
> 2. linguagem popular expressiva: A palavra "porreiro" é calão.
>
> Sinónimos: **gíria** e jargão

---

<sup>**1 - Baixo calão**: linguagem caracterizada por
 termos obscenos ou grosseiros.</sup>

Comment: Baixo calão seria sinônimo de Calão. https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/Discuss%C3%A3o:cal%C3%A3o.

Comment: Não senhor, Baixo calão é baixo calão. Tipo baixo nível. Esse link não diz nada disso @MeuChapeu...

Comment: `Baixo calão é quase um sinónimo`

Comment: É quase, mas não é um sinónimo. Falta o quase lol. Eu ao dizer "O meu dia foi porreiro" estou a usar calão e não estou a usar baixo calão.

Comment: Portanto é errado dizer que calão significa palavra grosseira ou palavrão, palavra de baixo nível.

Comment: Não é errado. Só porque vocês portugueses acham que é errado, não quer dizer que é errado no Brasil. pesquise Calão no Google é ele vai te mostrar vários significados. Dentre eles está `linguajar rude, grosseiro; geringonça, gíria.`

Comment: @MeuChapeu eu fui buscar fontes dos dois países, dicionários. Baixo calão também é calão, é certo dizer que "palavra grosseira ou palavrão, palavra de baixo nível" é calão. Mas calão não é só isso.

Comment: Alias a tua fonte do google só confirma isto que eu disse ^^^

Comment: Sim, eu sei que não é só isso. Mas você disse -> `Portanto é errado dizer que calão significa palavra grosseira`. O que não é verdade.

Comment: É verdade sim @MeuChapeu, dizeres "Calão = Significa palavra grosseira ou palavrão, palavra de baixo nível.(No Brasil)." é errado porque não é só isso. Estás a induzir as pessoas em erro. Ainda por cima fazes a definição de Gíria como se fosse outra coisa que nada tem a ver. e são sinónimos na verdade.

Comment: @MeuChapeu Alias Baixo calão também é Gíria. Eu punha agora na minha resposta " Gíria = Significa palavra grosseira ou palavrão, palavra de baixo nível." Isto estava certo? Mas Gíria também significa isso...

Comment: Poste as fontes do que estás a falar.

Comment: Estão em cima na minha resposta e na tua, se calão é sinonimo de gíria então gíria também tem de conter o baixo calão.

Comment: "sinónimo - Palavra que tem o mesmo significado que outra ou outras" Como é que tu tens duas palavras que são sinónimos e definições diferentes?

Comment: No BRASIL, NO BRASIL. Gíria é o que nos usamos para se comunicar em grupos, pode conter calão. Calão quando usamos palavras de baixo nível para ofender outras pessoas.

Comment: @MeuChapeu estás a dar uma resposta baseada no que se costuma dizer (aqui também se usa o termo calão para palavras de baixo nível) mas isso nada tem a ver com a definição correta das palavras.

Comment: Eu já debati tudo que tinha a debater sobre este assunto. Está bem explicada a minha resposta, e até a fonte da tua resposta faz da minha correta. Agora a comunidade que se pronuncie sobre isso.

Comment: Eu concordo contigo @JorgeB. Pra resumir podemos dizer assim, todo "termo obsceno" pode ser um calão, mas nem todo calão é um "termo obsceno". Sou brasileiro e tenho o mesmo entendimento que o seu.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o problema é que as pessoas estão habituadas a associar "calão" a "termo obsceno" e acham que por isso é certo.

Comment: @JorgeB. falar a verdade eu raramente ouvi/li alguém fazer isto. Pode ser algo regional (não quer dizer que esteja certo) por "mal uso", então sim você esta certo nisto *também*, talvez seja um "mal uso".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento por "**mau** uso" ;)

Comment: Kk @JorgeB. "mal" persegue os meus textos o.0 ...

Answer (score 5):

**Calão** = Significa palavra grosseira ou palavrão, palavra de baixo nível.(No Brasil).

Exemplo: Palavras que você usaria para xingar algo ou alguém.

**Jargão** = Termos técnicos de uma determinada área.

Exemplo: `peticionar`(Advogacia) = Para leigos seria algo como "entrar com a ação" ao "pedir ao juiz".

**Gíria** = Linguagem particular, usado por determinado grupo social, serve para facilitar a comunicação entras as pessoas desse grupo.

Exemplos:

No sul nos referimos ao pão francês como `cacetinho`. Em outros lugares se você falar isso, será mal interpretado.

O mesmo ocorre para as palavras `Guri` e `Guria` que seriam o mesmo que `Menino` e `Menina`.

Isso é no Brasil, já em Portugal ou outro país que fale português os significados podem ser diferentes.

Segundo definições do Google.

[image: Google sobre Calão here]

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas acho que houve uma confusão **Calão** é uma coisa e baixo-calão é outra. Poderia rever. Grato.

Comment: Pelo que sei baixo calão é errado pois calão já significa baixo. Ou você quis dizer jargão?

Comment: Pelo dicionário de língua portuguesa: 1. Linguagem considerada grosseira ou rude. 2. Linguagem de um grupo restrito. = GÍRIA

Comment: Não entendi o por que do -1? O que está errado em minha resposta?

Comment: @MeuChapeu Não fui eu quem lançou o `-1`, mas suponho que seja discordancia quanto a palavra **Calão**.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, o cara que deu `-1` podia se manifestar, para poder saber o que está errado na resposta, para corrigir.

Comment: Fui eu que dei -1 porque calão não tem de ser maldoso. Eu dizer "bue da fixe" é calão.

Comment: E pelo que pesquisei no Brasil é igual a isto: http://www.lexico.pt/calao/

Comment: Mas esse site lexico é de portugal. O Dicionário Michaelis está diferente. `linguagem caracterizada por termos obscenos ou grosseiros.`  -> http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=cal%E3o

Comment: E foi por isso que no lado coloquei entre parêntesis `BRASIL` por que no brasil é uma coisa e em Portugal pode ter outro significado.

Comment: E no final da resposta está dizendo `Isso é no Brasil, já em Portugal ou outro país que fale português os significados podem ser diferentes.`

Comment: @MeuChapeu não devemos estar a ver as mesmas coisas: "**Calão**: Linguagem especial, peculiar a ciganos, fadistas, larápios, vadios etc. 2 Gíria, geringonça. **Baixo calão**: linguagem caracterizada por termos obscenos ou grosseiros." em http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=cal%E3o

Comment: Na tua fonte, na definição de calão está Gíria também, o que dá razão ao meu ponto de vista, calão não é só aquilo que definiste nesta resposta.

Comment: Talvez as desavenças decorram da interpretação de `rude` e `grosseiro`. Pelo que eu entendi (até com a consulta em outros dicionários), a rudez e grosseria nesse significado está mais direcionada ao distanciamento da norma culta. Não se trata necessariamente de palavras ofensivas. Por isso, o uso de "baixo" para designar quando um `calão` é não só rude e grosseiro, como essencialmente ofensivo.

Comment: @MeuChapeu eu aprecio a resposta, no entanto sou brasileiro e nunca ouvi em nenhum lugar o uso da palavra *calão* pra determinar palavras como "ofensas". Vou dizer assim: Todo "termo obsceno" pode ser um calão, mas nem todo calão é um "termo obsceno".

Comment: @LuizVieira mas o autor da resposta diz "Calão = Significa palavra grosseira ou palavrão, palavra de baixo nível.(No Brasil)." que é bem diferente do que diz nos dicionários. Se fosse com a intenção que você diz eu teria deixado passar. Assim está a deturpar a definição de calão, porque muitas vezes as pessoas simplificam baixo calão só para calão,erradamente.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu não estava defendendo a resposta. Também acho ela equivocada, pois concordo que calão é diferente de baixo calão. A minha colocação é que a interpretação de "grosseiro" é que está errada (porque grosseiro nesse contexto talvez signifique aquém da norma culta, e não ofensivo).