# É correto reescrever "diferença entre X e Y" para "diferença de X e Y"? Em que variações?

Tags: expressões, variações

Como português, sempre disse e escrevi "a diferença *entre* um porco e um javali", "a diferença *entre* um selo e um avião", etc.

À medida que fui lendo algumas entradas neste site, surgiu também a mesma expressão com uma diferença na preposição de ligação, nomeadamente *"de"* em vez de *"entre"*. Exemplos: [Qual a diferença de gíria ou calão?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/105/84) e [Qual a diferença de "esse", "este" e "aquele"?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/2/84)

Diria até que no português de Portugal, tal coisa não é permitida, e a minha pesquisa não me trouxe esclarecimento de se se trata da forma usada mais frequentemente no Brasil.

Em que variantes do Português é permitida a expressão "diferença *de* «X» e «Y»", se alguma, ao contrário do típico "diferença *entre* «X» e «Y»"?

Comment: Não tens nenhum exemplo de "diferença de «X» e «Y»"?

Comment: @JorgeB. Atualizada com exemplos.

Comment: Eu acho que o que acontece ai nesses casos é a omissão do "usar", por exemplo, "Qual a diferença de (**usar**) gíria ou calão?"

Comment: Pois não sei. É por isso que perguntei.

Comment: @JorgeB. parece-me (tanto pela resposta aceite, como pela tradução inglesa da pergunta) que naquele caso o significado é `qual é a diferença entre a definição da palavra gíria e a definição da palavra calão?`... mas para "usar", a construção parece-me mal; eu usaria "qual é a diferença entre usar lápis ou usar caneta?" ou "que diferença faz usar lápis ou caneta?".

Comment: @ANeves tens razão. Estava a ver os títulos das perguntas sem o contexto das mesmas.

Comment: @ANeves Eu me perguntava por que estas questões não têm verbo — *qual **é** a  diferença entre X e Y*. Parece-me um pouco estranho, mas ninguém disse nada sobre isso.

Comment: @tchrist muito bem visto.

Answer (score 3):

Não se usa "a diferença de X e Y".

As únicas formas correntes no Português do Brasil são:

- a diferença entre X e Y
- a diferença de X para Y

Comment: Então os exemplos que o OP deu estão errados?

Comment: @JorgeB.  "usar lápis ou caneta" está ok.  Mas se tu incluis "qual a diferença entre......", eu diria "E' ao invés de "OU".  Não confundir com "tanto faz usar lápis ou caneta."   "Qual a diferença de.... " pode não ser errado, mas ninguém diz.

Comment: "As únicas formas correntes no Português do Brasil" se são as duas únicas formas corretas é porque as formas dos exemplo estão erradas?

Comment: @JorgeB. De uso "corrente" é uma coisa.  "errado" é outra.

Comment: Erro meu, peço desculpa li sempre "corretas" em vez de "correntes". -.-

Comment: Acho também importante apontar a validez da expressão, e não apenas se é usado ou se é corrente. Isto porque, naturalmente, vários erros de língua portuguesa são usados até com frequências não desprezáveis.